# $state didn't navigate properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to navigate from page A to B, so in my page A (history.html) view I did this

```
<a href="#/history/{{data.id}}">
    <li class="item">
    {{data.items}}
    </li>
</a>
```

and in my app.js the state is set like this

```
.state('app.history', {
    url: "/history",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/history.html",
            controller: 'historyCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('app.history2', {
    url: "/history/:id",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/history2.html",
            controller: 'history2Ctrl'
        }
    }
})
```

So supposedly it should be fine but it navigated to somewhere, what else is needed? Am I miss something? I visit the link manually by adding some numbers at the end, eg http://localhost:8100/#/app/history/123 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-href instead:

```
<a ng-href="{{'#/app/history/'+data.id}}">
    <li class="item">
    {{data.items}}
    </li>
    </a>
```

Also it would be better if you could nest `a` inside `li`

```
<li class="item">
    <a ng-href="{{'#/app/history/'+data.id}}">
       {{data.items}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I checked the dom, it render as the same thing even if I use normal href="", this proof that the problem is not at here.

Comment: but I couldn't figured out where is the mistake.. I have working example within the same project, it look like this http://pastebin.com/1bKGrrTs

Comment: It's not because of ng-repeat. As app is the parent view and app.history means url must contain app/history in the url. that's why it was not working before. updated answer with /app/history. And still u would prefer using ng-href as some data is dynamic in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this

```
<div class="list">
    <a ng-repeat="data in savedData" href="#/app/history/{{data.id}}">
      {{data.items}}
    </a>
</div>
```

which I have no idea why lol

Comment: before this, data was not present in the scope? I see you've savedData array from which you are accessing data.id currently

Comment: nope, before this I do have savedData in my ng-repeat, not sure why I have to take ng-repeat down, to be the same line with the href.

Comment: is it due to use of /history instead of /app/history?

Comment: @DeanJason In your question, you've not mentioned /app in the url. So it could also be the reason why it didn't work initially. And also later only you've added data field via ng-repeat.

Comment: ok. But still try it might be the case Because as said by @mohamedrias you only used data field in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use *ng-href* instead of *href*?

As I now, href link may be wrong if the angular library doesn't finish loading at the time user click on it.